# ast.literal_eval will convert unicode code point from \uxxxx to \\uxxxx, how to avoid?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, unicode

For example, here is the code to handle this json file

```
json.loads(u"\"{\\\"title\\\": \\\"\\\\u5927\\\"}\"")
```

**json.loads** will convert it to a unicode string, see below

```
{"title": "\u5927"}
```

here is the code to handle unicode string

```
ast.literal_eval(json.loads(u"\"{\\\"title\\\": \\\"\\\\u5927\\\"}\""))
```

**ast.literal_eval** will convert it to a dictionary, see below

```
{'title': '\\u5927'}
```

But what I want is a dictionary with below content

```
{'title': '\u5927'}
```

Comment: see my update, use `json.load()` instead for file object

Comment: Why are you trying to use `ast.literal_eval()` here?

Comment: @duskwuff I want to convert the unicode string to a dictionary

Comment: @ybbaigo, please do not change OP requirements without saying **edit** keyword, that confused people who sees what the answer already provided, and this is rather rude. Again, I have posted another solution which totally works on your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.loads("{\"title\": \"\\u5927\"}")` will return a dictionary, so you don't need the `ast.literal_eval` at all.

```
d = json.loads("{\"title\": \"\\u5927\"}")

print d
{u'title': u'\u5927'}

type(d)
Out[2]: dict
```

For the full `json.loads()` json to python conversion, please see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json-to-py-table).

If you're trying to parse a file, use `json.load()` without the **s** like this:

```
with open('your-file.json') as f:
    # you can change the encoding to the one you need
    print json.load(f, encoding='utf-8')
```

Test:

```
from io import StringIO

s = StringIO(u"{\"title\": \"\\u5927\"}")

print json.load(s)
{u'title': u'\u5927'}
```

#### Update

OP has totally changed what the json should be parsed, here is another solution, parse the json again:

```
json.loads(json.loads(u"\"{\\\"title\\\": \\\"\\\\u5927\\\"}\""))
Out[6]: {u'title': u'\u5927'}
```

This is because the first `json.loads` convert the string (non-json) to a json string, parse it again with `json.loads` will deserialize it eventually.

Comment: since I'm loading a json file, you can't copy it to the console directly. Please try json.loads(u"\"{\\\"title\\\": \\\"\\\\u5927\\\"}\"")

Comment: @ybbaigo, If that is a file, you should use `json.load()`, without **s**

Comment: Sorry for confusing, it's my bad. Assuming I'm parsing a unicode string not loading a json file. I have updated my question, let's focus on  the issue about **ast.literal_eval**

Comment: @ybbaigo, no, if you are trying to parse **json**, there is no reason to use `eval` at all.

Comment: Thanks @Anzel, your update solved my problems. But double **json.loads** looks weird. am I using json file wrong? I'm using `requests.post(..., json = "{"title" : "\u5927"}")` to send request, and using tornado server to handle the request, the content of request.body is `"\"{\\\"title\\\": \\\"\\\\u5927\\\"}\""`

Comment: @ybbaigo, that's because it isn't **json**, it's just a string (double json'ed). reason is you send the `requests` post with `json=`**string**. You should instead send a dictionary like: `requests.post(..., json={"title" : "\u5927"})` without the parent `"`

Comment: Exactly, you are saving my life!

Comment: @ybbaigo, surely my dear :-) This answer could be much simpler if you have posted with last comment as a question though. Anyway, glad it's solved for you